# reading data from json file then writing into an embed?

Tags: python, python-3.5, discord, discord.py

So I was working on a new feature on a discord bot that would tell you all the parties(clans) in the server, and the clan info is stored inside a json file, I would like to send it to the user though send_message(), but it keeps returning this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)
after a bit of research it means that there's more than 2000 characters inside the message, and I was wondering what's wrong with my code, any suggestion is welcomed, thanks for reading this. #I_Love_Troubleshooting

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def partylist(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    await partylist(user)


async def partylist(user):
    partylist = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )
    partylist.set_author(name="Parties")
    with open(url2, 'r') as w:
        file = json.load(w)
        for item in file:
            partylist.add_field(name=item,value="",inline=False)
    w.close()
    await client.say(user,embed=partylist)
```

```
#This is the json file
{"clan2": {"Members": "ShareYourGraves#9977"}, "clan1": {"Members": "||CATENARY||#9105,"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you just send a limited amount of information to the users the allow them to get more detailed info via different commands or make them view it on webpage

```py
data={"clan2": {"Members": "ShareYourGraves#9977"}, "clan1": {"Members": "||CATENARY||#9105,"}}

async def send_data(user):
    emb=discord.Embed(title='Data')
    clans=[name for name in data]
    emb.add_field(name='clan names',value=" ,".join(clans))
    await bot.send_message(user,embed=emb)
```

Comment: ummmm that doesn't seem to work, it still says that the embed is too large

Comment: As suggested, you should consider sending it by parts by the allowed amount, if you wish to display them all at once then make a web-page for users to view it. Max characters per message is `2000`